# How to repair cut joist around pipe *after* framing and drywall

Tags: bathroom, framing, joists

I'm finishing my attic and have just realized that my rough carpenter screwed up by not addressing a cut joist. In photo 1, you can see that the joists have been sistered with LVLs, but there is a gap in one joist around the vent pipe (lower right). The small pieces of wood connecting the two sections of the original joist are resting on top of a wall below (perpendicular), but it is not a load bearing wall. In photo 2 you can see this area up close as well as the framing for a bathroom. The room has since been drywalled and tiled.

We were about to put the toilet in, when I realized I had better be sure that corner can take the 100+ pounds it will add. I am going to set the toilet box in the corner and see if I detect any deflection over the next month or so. (I'm putting joint compound along the top and bottom of the baseboards and will watch to see if cracks form.) If I see even the slightest movement I will ask my rough carpenter to come back and address the cut joist, which will mean breaking into the ceiling of the finished rooms below.

However, I'm not sure exactly what the fix should be. Maybe sister the two sides of the cut joist, except they do not align exactly. Maybe cut off each side and and put headers connecting the two pieces to the adjacent joists? Except that the adjacent joists should be doubled, and that will not be easy--the rooms below are finished. Maybe they can be strengthened with a steel place?

[image: joists before floor]

[image: after framing]

Comment: "but it is not a load bearing wall" ... *surprise*!! It probably is a load-bearing wall now, even if it's not intended to be ...

Comment: I’m fascinated by the triple joist staggered sistered splice.

Comment: I know, it's a disaster. But I need to deal with it somehow. Any advice welcome.

Comment: I can not see the relationship between the two photo's. I see tragic things in both but do not understand the relationship of the two.

Comment: @AlaskaMan It took me a few minutes, but I figured out the relationship: the second picture was taken standing a few feet further to the right - looking straight on at the area instead of at an angle - and was taken further along in the construction process after the wall framing was added. If you look down into the floor in the second picture, you will see the triple-staggered splice. If you look at the first picture, you will see a black rag(?) covering the end of the PVC pipe that is shown in the second picture.

Comment: you got it! now do you have any suggestions for dealing with this?

Comment: I'm not a PE, just an experienced DIY'er, so someone will have to tell if this isn't up to code, but this is the minimum I'd do. The joists look like 2x6's. Replace the staggered splice with a single 2x6 going at least 18" each side of the cut, with at least 3 lag bolts each side, staggered so they're not on the same grain. If you need more thickness to clear the drain stack, use blocks at least as long as the sintering board and bolt all the way thru all 3 boards (joist, spacers, sister). Screw the plywood subfloor to everything. Consider cross brace under the toilet also.

Comment: At a minimum, I would re-do that triple-sister, making the middle 'layer' come as close as possible to the angled fittings. I'd use lots of glue and at least 4 lag screws on each end. Then once the last sister was put on (again with glue/lag screws) I''d drill thru all three and put two 1/2" lag bolts on each end with flat washers on both ends and lock-washer on the nuts. Then I would cover these with grease or something to prevent rust.  I would also tie the two ends of the cut floor plate with a piece of 1/4" flat steel and lag screws. That was one terrible hack-job.

Comment: Well--I have not done anything about this cut joist yet, and instead I've been watching for movement. I put patches of drywall compound on the corners of the baseboards near the joist and on some trim in this area in the ceiling below. That was back in May, and now it's almost November. I have not seen any cracks appear in the joint compound. I'm wondering if there's enough support from adjoining joists (connected through subfloor and flooring) that the cut sides of the joist are not going to sink. Although I realize it may just take a while longer.